# Why is the polarization of the capacitor flipped in this diagram?

Tags: circuit-analysis, clamp

As far as I know, the vertical line of the polar capacitor symbol represents the positive side. In this diagram, it is somehow is flipped.

The output voltage does not make any sense to me, either.

[image]

Comment: Unless you’re specifically studying the breakdown behaviour of polarized capacitors I think the diagram is just incorrect and should have an unpolarized capacitor symbol.

Comment: @Bryan Are you sure, buddy? Because I have to make a complaint about our teacher. She gave us this thing with her wonderful lecture that went over our heads.

Comment: at the end of the day it's only a symbol. I had a friend who frequently challenged faculty on lesson content and general pedagogy, he got his degree 8 years and three institutions later. Your job in school is to "learn how to learn" as I heard once, and sometimes that means making good guesses as to what's expected.

Answer (score 0):

The RC time constant is much higher than input frecuency, so once the capacitor is charged in negative voltage input half cycle, will keep positive until next negative. See simulation (Vc=Vo-Vi), capacitor voltage is about +24 V all time.

[image]

[image]

In case time constant is close to input frecuency, capacitor will discharge, Vc  will change polarity and non polarized type is mandatory.
See waveforms for R=100 Ohm.

[image]